# How to click in a pop up using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

How can I click "Allow" in the pop up using Selenium with java? There is no way to inspect this pop up so I don't know the id, or name or xpath.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not an alert. This is a browser level notification.

Try these:

1. [How to handle browser level notification using Selenium Webdriver](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-handle-browser-level-notification-using-selenium-webdriver-maske)
2. [How to Disable Chrome notifications popup in Selenium WebDriver](http://www.qaautomated.com/2018/03/how-to-disable-chrome-notifications.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to allow :

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); //This will allow the access
```

To block the access use below code :

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

Comment: Thank you but is not working, I tried allowing that is what I need and the pop up is being displayed and in the Eclipse console I am receiving this message:   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544337 (8c0344a12e552148c185f7d5117db1f28d6c9e85),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.63

Comment: Yes this is not a alert. try the below comment

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for permissions prompts in WebDriver, though there is a [draft](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#automation) of an endpoint to control them (as of writing, I believe no WebDriver implementation exposes them, and there is no Selenium API for them).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox profiles are to blame. I suggest creating and configuring a profile for Selenium to use that suits your needs.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310797/using-selenium-webdriver-and-python-how-do-i-suppress-the-prompt-to-share-my-ca

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(5000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm for me. But I know this is not the right way of doing it.

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(3000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```